# How to avoid execution of resource if is not being called by localhost?

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, chmod, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

Is it possible to prevent anyone from entering a resource in an specific directory? May be with `.htaccess` or changed its group or permissions may be?

For example, the resource is in:

```
/myRoute/to/resource.html
/myRoute/to/resource2.html 
/myRoute/to/resource3.html
```

Path to prevent from entering

```
/myRoute/to
```

So, if I am directly requesting `/myRoute/to/resource.html` I get a **forbidden** sign but ***if its my web application who is requesting it, then it can read it***.

This is used for the **angularjs** template handler, I need to have those `.html` files but prevent anyone else from executing them.

Comment: This is not something you can do without server side scripting. If you make a request from a page, the page sends the client's IP address with the request, which would only resolve to localhost if you are making the request from a browser on the same machine as the server. You need to write a server side template handling engine of some sort that will only respond to requests from a specific page, such as those that pass a valid csrf token or something.

Comment: what version of apache are you using?

Comment: @mopsyd thanks for your opinion. I think there must be a way.

Comment: @PanamaJack I am using apache 2.2